# Integrate Bluetooth application to User Interface application

Tags: android, service, bluetooth, iot

So far we have developed two applications:

**Bluetooth Application**

This app handles the connection and communication to a bluetooth device. It can preform all kinds of tasks on the device but has a very bad user interface. It does this in a single Activity.

**User Interface Application**

This app has a shiny new interface but no bluetooth logic yet. Built with some Activities and Fragments.

**Problem**

How do I integrate the bluetooth app into my UI app? I need the bluetooth functionality to be accessible from different activities and fragments within the UI app. I still want to keep it modular and practice "separation of concern".

*Ways Im thinking of are:*

- I add the bluetooth app as a service so it can run
  independently in the background. (This might not be good since I don't really need to keep the connection open always when not having the app open.)
- I make a library out of the bluetooth application which I add to the UI app.
- I break out the bluetooth functionality to a separate static class that I then add to the other application.